# Redirect /nameoftheorganization to /home/nameoftheorganization which calls Home.php controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using php codeigniter on a project that has several organizations. Each organization will have its own website, I need to redirect each user to its organization website according to the organization name.

I got this partially running. Using localhost as example:

localhost/application/ -> Goes to the correct view;

localhost/home/nameoftheorganization -> Goes to the correct organization view;

But is there a way to eliminate the "Home" controller?

My routes.php looks like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'home/page_not_found';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

My Home.php controller looks like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // Your own constructor code
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->library('session');
    // $this->load->library('stripe');
    /*cache control*/
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
    if (!$this->session->userdata('cart_items')) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('cart_items', array());
    }
}

public function index() {
    $this->home();
}

public function home($domain = '') {
    if($domain != ''){
        $frontend = $this->crud_model->get_frontend_information($domain);
    }else{
       $frontend = $this->crud_model->get_frontend_information('myapp'); 
    }

    foreach($frontend AS $arr){
        if(is_array($arr)){
            $website[$arr['key']] = $arr['value'];
            }
        }

    $this->session->set_userdata('website', $website);


    $page_data['page_name'] = "home";
    $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('home');
    $this->load->view('frontend/'.get_frontend_settings('theme').'/index', $page_data);
}
```

htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there a way to eliminate the "Home" controller?

this, in your example, can be achieved with the following route:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/home/$1';
```

this will feed your `home()` function of the Home.php controller.

**above** that route you may want to add routes to get to any other function within that Home.php controller

don't forget about the three reserved routes, mainly:

`$route['default_controller'] = 'yourdefaultcontroller';`

so a complete route for your example could look like:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['about']='home/about';
$route['contact']='home/contact';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/home/$1';
$route['404_override'] = 'sitemanager/my_404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

now you can type *www.yoursite.com/organization1*, which will be sent to controller `Home.php`, with the `$id='organization1'`

note: You'll need to filter out requests which do not mach your database of organizations within your home() function and send them to your custom 404 page.

more about [Codeigniter Routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples)